# How can I set View size like percent of parent size?

Tags: android, view, scrollview

I make something like tab.
I have `HorizontalScrollView` with `LinearLayout` and few View in it.
I want to change width of my View depending on screen size (ScrollView or LinearLayout size)

to do this:

```
if (view1.size+view2.size + ... + viewn.size < scrollView.size)
{
   view1.setSize(scrollView.size/n);
   view2.setSize(scrollView.size/n);
   ...
   viewn.setSize(scrollView.size/n);
}
```

I try set something in `onMeasure`, but all decisions were wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ScrollView's size is not determinate and actually depends on the size of the children.

If you want to use the size of the screen and how many children you want to show on the screen which makes more sense, something like the following might work (not tested):

```
int children_on_screen = 3;
int size = getWidthOfTheScreen();

for(int i=0;i<yourLinearLayout.getChildCount();i++) {
   LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) yourLinearLayout.getChildAt(i).getLayoutParams();
   params.width = size / children_on_screen;
}
yourLinearLayout.requestLayout();
```